How to change crosses to ascending numbers
//@version=5
indicator("Crosses in body center", overlay=true)

var float avg_price = na

if not na(close) and not na(open)
    avg_price := (close + open) / 2

plot(avg_price, color = close > open ? color.lime : color.purple, linewidth=5, style=plot.style_cross)

How can I instruct the code to enumerate all the crosses appearing with ascending numbers? The counting should commence from 500 bars prior to the current bar. Therefore, the label on the bar 500 bars back will display '1', the subsequent one '2', and so forth.
I attempted to implement a counter, but I wasn't successful.

for last 500 bars, try this:
last500     = bar_index > last_bar_index - 500

bgcolor(
  last500 ? color.new(color.gray, 90) : na,
  title      = 'last500')

then you can use your counter
if last500
    youCounter

